# Bug/Issue tracker for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I would really like to port my website to Drupal 7, but my site requires an issue tracker. I tried the support module, but it seems heavily orientated towards support tickets (you must add clients, all users can't view eachothers tickets).

With the project issues module still working on complete Drupal 6 support, I really don't think I should be holding my breath.

What options are there, If I want a bug tracker on Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: Do It Yourself**

Add taxonomy terms

1. **Status** (Open, In Progress, Pending, Resolved, Closed) ,
2. **Priority**
   (Low, Normal, High)

Create content type ***Issue***,

- add fields title, body, status, priority.

Set roles

- Allow anonymous users to create content Issue
- Allow administrators to edit and delete content Issue

Extras:

Use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) for issue reporting

Use [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) for managing issues

Use [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) for setting issue management workflow

**Solution 2: Use an external issue management solution**

[Comparison of issue-tracking systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems)

I prefer an external solution because of its independency I can still handle issues even if my site is down.

Comment: Managed to get something going with your do it yourself solution. I prefer something integrated to drupal so I can have one unified look and feel to my site. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Project for D7 is http://3281d.com/2011/10/26/report-from-project-7-sprint coming. It's going to be a while so holding your breath is not advised... but it's coming.